# Angular - Spring Boot: Problema de CORS

Tags: angular, spring, cors

Estoy teniendo la siguiente dificultad: Cuando quiero acceder a información guardada en mi BD desde Spring (localhost:8080) accedo perfectamente, pero si quiero acceder a esa misma información desde una petición desde Angular (localhost:4200) me da problema de CORS.

En mi servicio de Angular lo tengo armado asi:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Clientes  } from "./clientes.interface";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
};

@Injectable()

export class ClientesService{

  urlBase:string = "http://localhost:8080/clientes"



  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  nuevoCliente( cliente:Clientes){
    return this.http.post( this.urlBase, cliente, httpOptions).pipe(map(data => data['id']));
  }
}
```

Y en Spring lo tengo armado de la siguiente forma:

```
package com.gestion.backend.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import com.gestion.backend.entidades.Cliente;
import com.gestion.backend.services.ClientesService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods= {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public class ClientesController {

    @Autowired
    ClientesService clientesService;


    // Traigo todos los clientes
    @GetMapping("/clientes")
    public List<Cliente> getCLientes(){
        return clientesService.getClientes();
    }

    // Traigo un usuario especifico
    @GetMapping("/clientes/{id}")
    public Cliente getCliente(@PathVariable Long id){
        System.out.println("ID" + id);

        return clientesService.getClienteById(id);
    }
}
```

En ambos lados aclaro lo de CORS...que me esta faltando para que no me de el error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/clientes' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el puerto del front end:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
```

y en ese orden, primero crossOrigin y luego la declaracion de restController

prueba borrando

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
};
```

y tambien borra esto:

```
  urlBase:string = "http://localhost:8080/clientes"
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder, probe haciendo eso y sigue igual!..

Answer (score 0):

Hola crea un clase donde puedas configurar el siguiente metodo
con la anotación @Configuration

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

        }           

    };          
}
```

Comment: Hola Edson! Gracias por responder...esta clase como la vinculo con mi clase clientes por ejemplo? Gracias!

Comment: en si con crear una clase con la anotacion @Configuration y con extends a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter debe de funcionar.