# ¿Como solucionar pedido de origen cruzado (CORS)? Spring + Angular

Tags: java, spring, http, cors, cabeceras-http

hace días que estoy intentando solucionar el famoso problema de orígenes cruzados (CORS) en mi servicio Spring.

Anteriormente en métodos GET con simplemente agregarla anotación `@CrossOrigin(origin = "*")` en la declaración de mi clase Controller ya se solucionaba.

El problema me volvió a aparecer al momento de utilizar un método PUT. Desde mi front-end (hecho en Angular 7) le envió un JSON a mi controller, el cual posee nuevamente  `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` declarado, pero aún así el browser insiste con que no puede realizarse la petición.

Intente colocando `@CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:4200",  allowedHeaders = "*")` tanto a nivel de clase como a nivel de método. Intente colocarle un proxy a mi frontEnd y tampoco funciono.

Intenté hasta cambiando de PUT a POST e indicarle especificamente a mi controller que metodos recibir en el crossOrigin y nada.

PD: No estoy utilizando ningun tipo de cookies.
Les comparto unas capturas y código para ilustrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Así se encuentra el encabezado de mi controlador actualmente:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200",  methods= {RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.OPTIONS})
public class ContactUpdateController {
```

Comment: Favor no colocar capturas del código, mejor copia y pegalo como texto. También pásate por [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta y sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Cambia el orden en el que declaras las cosas. Pon primero `@CrossOrigin( ... )` y luego en la siguiente linea tu controlador `@RestController`. Puedes ver la siguiente [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255969/angular-spring-boot-problema-de-cors/255975#255975). Saludos

Comment: Por un lado el origin es `http://localhost:4200`, evita el uso de '*', por otro lado para ver bien que estas mandando fijate en el navegador haciendo inspect->network, ahi seleccionando el request (puede ser un preflight OPTIONS que se mande o el request directamente asi que fijate). Ahí aparece tanto el method como todos los headers. Agrega eso a la pregunta. Por otro lado, también aclará si tu aplicación usa cookies y en todo caso si configuraste angular para mandar los requests con "withCredentials".

Comment: @Juan ya intente  colocando el origen como http://localhost:4200 y la anotación CrossOrigin por encima de la RestController. Ya adjunto la informacion del network. Por otro lado, en Angular, nunca configure  request withCredential, solo coloqué en el headers que iba a devover contenido del tipo JSON.

Comment: No es solo poner la url, tiene que estar todo alineado. Fijate de agregar eso a la pregunta y falta que confirmes si estás usando cookies, para la sesión por ejemplo.

Comment: No entiendo lo del alineado. Ya aclaré que no estoy utilizando cookies. Sigo con el mismo inconveniente.

Answer (score -1):

Tenia exactamente el mismo error, resulta que estaba hacienda mal la llamada al endpoint.

```
mi post era user/create
mi put era user/edit/{{email@user.com}}
```

Muchas veces es facil confundirse con cosas asi al hacer copy and paste, procura revisarlo.

..Por otra parte @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") en Springboot funciona de maravilla

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/306857)

Comment: Si bien fué hace ya 2 años el problema lo pude solucionar mediante otra respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/265924/como-solucionar-pedido-de-origen-cruzado-cors-en-spring
No era un problema en el path del endpoint, cualquier cosa pueden remitirse allí.