# ¿Como solucionar pedido de origen cruzado (CORS) en Spring?

Tags: java, angular, spring, http

estoy intentando realizar de manera exitosa la comunicación entre mi servicio back-end Spring y mi front-end en Angular vía http.

Recibo un bloqueo por la política de CORS al momento de intentar dicha comunicación. He colocado `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", methods={RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.OPTIONS})` a nivel de clase en mi controller y aun así no se me es permitida la comunicacion.

Vale aclarar que en otros servicios de mi aplicacion con la anotación @CrossOrigin fué suficiente para lograr pasar el bloqueo de CORS, ahora lo único que cambio fue que en vez de ser un método GET, es un método PUT.

No estoy utilizando Spring Security y si utilizo SpringBoot.

Headers que me muesta el dubugger de Chrome:

```
GENERAL
Request URL: http://localhost:9096/jcontact/upcontact
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: [::1]:9096
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 20
Date: Sat, 25 May 2019 23:05:14 GMT

REQUEST HEADERS
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/update
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

**PD**: No utilizo cookies, y también intente colocar la anotacion @CrossOrigin por encima de la @RestController.

Comment: Creo que ya tenias un pregunta por este tema. Necesitas fijarte y agregar a la pregunta todos los headers que estás mandando en el request. Eso lo podes ver en el navegador: inspect, network. Ahí seleccionas el request (un xhr) y al costado seleccionas el tab de headers o cabeceras.

Comment: Juan muchas gracias por el nuevo contacto, ahora entiendo a que te referías con los headers que querías ver, ahí actualizo la publicación.

Comment: Te pido confirmar dos cosas más: ¿Estas usando Spring Security? y saber si el proyecto es con Spring boot o no porque la configuración global es diferente.

Comment: Listo Juan, actualizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenté emular tu problema configurando CORS en un SpringBoot con un controller con un método mapeado a PUT y que devuelva una cabecera de content-length aparte de un json con datos.

**Antes que nada:**

> @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")

*Este annotation restringe el origen y permite todas las cabeceras y todos los métodos.*

**Lo que hice:**

Hice la configuración de CORS de 3 formas diferentes (Son independientes pero el que quiera o necesite puede usarlos en conjunto):

1) Con @CrossOrigin a nivel de método
2) Con @CrossOrigin a nivel de clase
3) Configurando CORS a nivel global

Las 2 primeras funcionaron directamente sin configuraciones adicionales.
En el caso de la tercera (configuración global), tuve que especificar los métodos permitidos y las cabeceras permitidas. Emulando lo que hice con `@CrossOrigin`, solo restringí el origen y permití todas las cabeceras y todos los métodos.

**El controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/xxx") // <- Asumí que tenés algo así pero no es necesario si el path está todo configurado en el método.
public class InfoController {


@PutMapping(path="/info", consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public Information postInfo(@RequestBody InfoParams infoParams) {
        Information rtn = new Information();
        rtn.date = infoParams.date;
        rtn.time = infoParams.time;
        rtn.temperature = "20º";
        return rtn;
    }

    // -- Esto es solo para el ejemplo --
    public static class Information{
        public String date;
        public String time;
        public String temperature;
    }

    public static class InfoParams{
        public String date, time;
    }
}
```

**Configuración a nivel de método:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@PutMapping(path="/info", consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public Information postInfo(@RequestBody InfoParams infoParams) {...}
```

**Configuración a nivel de clase:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/xxx") // <- Asumí que tenés algo así pero no es necesario si el path está todo configurado en el método.
    public class InfoController {...}
```

**Configuración global para Spring Boot**

(En mi prueba no use annotations de @CrossOrigin en el controller para esta configuración)

La clase `CorsdemoApplication` es la que arranca la aplicación, vos debes tener una clase así anotada con `@SpringBootApplication.`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CorsdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CorsdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Nota: Para emular la cabecera de content-length use [este filtro que encontré acá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34305712/2225960). No incluí el filtro en el código más arriba.

En la única opción que tuve el error que te apareció a vos, fue cuando tenía mal configurada la opción 3 de configuración global.

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Fantástico, se quito el problema con el request OPTIONS y el bloqueo de CORS, solo que ahora aparece  PUT http://localhost:9096/jcontact/upcontact 404 ...esto creo que de debe quizas a que le esta llegando nulo al back end ese json.

Comment: 404 es not found, fijate que tengas bien la ruta (path o paths que estes usando)

Comment: Listo hermano!, venía nulo un atributo pero además habia una barra de mas en el path! jaja mil gracias por la dedicación , fuiste el único que me pudo ayudar.

Comment: De nada. Si te sirvió la respuesta aceptala con el tilde verde :)