# Error CORS SpringBoot Java

Tags: java, angular, api, spring-boot, rest

El problema que tengo, es que corro mi servidor y uno de mis componentes en angular, no me muestra el html que le ingrese y me muestra un error que dice:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   :8080/api1:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>   core.js:6210 ERROR HttpErrorResponse

Tengo bien configurado el `CrossOrigin` en Java, ya que otras funcionalidades si me funcionan, adjuntare el código de mi `api rest`

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    @CrossOrigin (origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public class ReclamoController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/ADMIN/pendientes/respuesta")
    public void insertarRespuesta(@RequestBody Respuesta respuesta) throws Exception{
    Fecha fecha = new Fecha();
    String slarespuesta = fecha.compararFechas(respuesta);
    respuesta.setSLA_respuesta(slarespuesta);
    RespuestaDAO.insertarRespuesta(respuesta);
    }
    }
```

El componente de angular que no se visualiza, seria este:

```
     <div class="contenedor" *ngIf="respuesta">
     <h2>Reclamo N°...</h2>
      <div class="contenedor1">
      <h3>Estado reclamo: Pendiente/No pendiente.</h3>

        <h3>Detalles Reclamo {{respuesta.num_reclamo}}</h3>
        <hr>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;" >
            <mat-label>Numero de reclamo</mat-label>
            <input matInput #num_reclamo value="{{respuesta.num_reclamo}}" disabled="true">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
            <mat-label>RUT del ADMIN</mat-label>
            <input matInput #rut_admin value="{{respuesta.rut_admin}}" >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
            <mat-label>RESPUESTA DEL ADMIN</mat-label>
            <input matInput #texto_respuesta value="{{respuesta.texto_respuesta}}">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
            <mat-label>Fecha de Respuesta YYYY/MM/DD</mat-label>
            <input matInput #fecha_respuesta value="{{respuesta.fecha_respuesta}}">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
            <mat-label>SLA Respuesta</mat-label>
            <input matInput #SLA_respuesta value="{{respuesta.SLA_respuesta}}">
        </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="volver()" style="margin: 1em;">Volver 
    Atras</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="guardar(num_reclamo.value, rut_admin.value, 
    texto_respuesta.value, fecha_respuesta.value, SLA_respuesta.value)">Guardar</button>

    </div>
```

Y acá su component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RespuestaService } from 'src/app/services/respuesta-service.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Respuesta } from 'src/models/Respuesta';

@Component({
selector: 'app-respuesta-de-reclamo',
templateUrl: './respuesta-de-reclamo.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./respuesta-de-reclamo.component.css']
})
export class RespuestaDeReclamoComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() respuesta: Respuesta;
constructor(
private respuestaService:RespuestaService,
private ruta: ActivatedRoute,
private ubicacion: Location
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
}

volver(){
this.ubicacion.back();
}

guardar(num_reclamo:number, rut_admin:number, texto_respuesta:string, fecha_respuesta:string, 
SLA_respuesta: string){
this.respuestaService.responderReclamo({num_reclamo, rut_admin, texto_respuesta, fecha_respuesta, 
SLA_respuesta} as Respuesta)
  .subscribe(_=>this.volver());
}
}
```

```
    static public int insertarRespuesta(Respuesta respuesta) throws Exception, SQLException {
        Connection conn = Conexion.obtenerConexion();
        String estadoReclamo = "RESPONDIDO";
        String insert = "insert into Respuesta(num_reclamo, rut_admin, texto_respuesta, fecha_respuesta, SLA_respuesta) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        ps.setLong(1, respuesta.getNum_reclamo());
        ps.setLong(2, respuesta.getRut_admin());
        ps.setString(3, respuesta.getTexto_respuesta());
        ps.setString(4, respuesta.getFecha_respuesta());
        ps.setString(5, respuesta.getSLA_respuesta());
        int resultado = ps.executeUpdate();
        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: por si acaso https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255969/angular-spring-boot-problema-de-cors

Comment: Persiste el problema, pero gracias

Comment: como esta declarado este objeto RespuestaDAO ?

Comment: Lo edite y añadi el respuesta dao

Comment: Fijate en herramientas de desarrollador en el browser cuales son los request que está haciendo aplicación y agrega esa info a la pregunta. Puede que tengas uno o dos, en el caso de dos el primero sería un options. En la pregutna coloca el request, el metodo, los headers del request, y respecto al error fijate si no dice nada mas acerca del error. PTI: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin/220984#220984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías crear una clase preferentemente a nivel de src/main/java/com.tuProjecto/configurations

con una anotación de @configuración que aplicará automáticamente al iniciar spring para agregar cors a tus URLs

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CORSConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer CORSConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT","DELETE");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias, tuve el mismo problema y tras más de una hora buscándolo en el SO en inglés llegué a esta publicación y por fin se pudo solucionar. A lo que yo tengo entendido la anotación @CrossOrigin debería ser suficiente pero por alguna razón no funciona como lo esperado, sabrás a qué se debe esto?