# Access to XMLHttpRequest at "URL" has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: reactjs, axios

esoty utiilizando una API en el cual se envia un correo electronico, estoy utilizando `axios` para hacer la peticion POST desde un proyecto con ReactJs

```javascript
onst resp = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                address: mail,
                subject: 'testeru',
                htmlBody: 'test test test',
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
```

Cuando ejecuto ese código, no envia la petición y me arroja el siguente mensaje en al consola del navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado la API funciona correctamente si utilizo Postman para probar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servidor no tiene problemas porque hay muchas aplicaciones creadas con `PHP` y `C#` en el cual consumen esa API sin ningun problema. Tambien probe usar `fetch` pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

Como podria solucionar este problema? Existe otra alternativa que no sea `axios` o `fetch`

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) hace referencia a la prohibición de compartir recursos entre dominios distintos; para solucionar eso, debes configurar en tu backend el acceso a tus datos. Postman no te lanza esa excepción, simplemente porque ese tipo de validaciones las omite.

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que el axios las omite?

Comment: El link que te deje en el comentario anterior tiene todo lo que necesitas para que lo implementes en tu front; pero te recomiendo que - en caso que puedas tener acceso al codigo backend -, lo realices ahí.

Comment: Ahora lo voy a mirar, ya probe muchas cosas. Por otro lado no tengo control de backend, tecnimcanete funciona todo correctamente y esta todo  bien configurado

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Angular - Spring Boot: Problema de CORS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255969/angular-spring-boot-problema-de-cors)

Comment: No, por otro lado parece que ahi no lo pudieron solucionar, y estan usando AngularJS

Comment: No puedo hacer que tenga el mismo comportamiento que Postman?

Comment: La validación de CORS es a nivel de navegador, lo único que puedes es hacer es realizar configuraciones.

Comment: Quiero saber de donde proviene el problema. Deberia hacer un reclamo al administradaor del servidor? Lo que no entiendo es que en otras aplicaciones funciona correctamente la peticion. Lo unico que cambia es que estoy usando ReactJs con axios